# difference between get and come by

Tags: difference

1. You don't **get** such wonderful opportunities too often.
2. You don't **come by** such wonderful opportunities too often.

What's the difference ?

Comment: I'd say "Such wonderful opportunities are hard to come by". FYI I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Probably not much difference. But more context is really needed. In my mind "come by" indicates a more passive action compared with "get".

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in their meaning in the examples provided:  wonderful opportunities are rare ... wonderful opportunities present themselves rarely...one does not happen upon wonderful opportunities often.

"Get" is by far the more common.

But the two locutions could have very different connotations in other circumstances.

*How did you come by that fancy camera?* versus *Where did you get that fancy camera?*

"How did you come by" could be understood to be an insinuation that the person with the camera had obtained it illicitly, whereas the question "get" is neutral; the questioner who uses "get" might well expect an answer such as "My uncle gave it to me as a graduation gift".

Comment: I find the change in "connotations* in your example sentence is due to the differences in phrases: *how did you* versus *where.* To me, *How did you get that fancy camera* can be just as much a non-neutral insuation as using *come by* in the same sentence.

Comment: But can you make "come by" neutral?

Comment: Hi, TRomano, in my part of the woods, *How did you come by that fancy camera* is just as neutral as if one used *get.* The same seems to me for the [sample sentences](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/come-by?q=come+by) in the ODO.

Comment: Are you from the South?

Comment: Is the Oxford Dictionary Online "from the south"? :)

Comment: When the questioner uses "How did you come by {something}?", there is the implication that something unusual went on, not necessarily illegal; such things are not easy to acquire.  "How did you get...?" does not have such implications. The ODO has *manage* to acquire.

Comment: Based on the ODO, I conclude that *come by* means more like *manage to get,* thus *come by* implies an explanation (but not necessarily an insuation) that is not (always?) implied by *get.* I guess *get **such** a fancy camera* asks for an explanation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In my answer to the OP's question, I was giving a kind of worst-case scenario for possible misunderstanding. Didn't mean to imply that come by would always imply an insinuation of wrongdoing. The points you make have helped to clarify the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the difference is in the [Grammatical Mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood) of the words. The word **get** as used here implies an Indicative mood, meaning that the statement is a fact. The phrase **come by**, on the other hand, implies an Inferential mood, meaning that the statement is a possibility but doesn't completely confirm itself as fact.

To illustrate, consider the ownership of an apple. You could reasonably *come by* an apple without actually acquiring possession of it, even though it is strongly implied that you did. To *get* an apple, on the other hand, you must acquire, have acquired, or be expecting to acquire it; there is no ambiguity about its possession.

Comment: -1 *Get* and *come by* are near synonyms. There is no change of mood in the OP's sentences.

Comment: @CarSmack the words may be synonyms, but they do indeed reflect a subtle change in grammatical mood. The full implications of that mood may vary from locality to locality, but that doesn't change the fact that there is a difference.